# JSONB column not updated to NULL value

Tags: spring, hibernate, sql-update, jsonb, hibernate-types

I have a classic multilayered REST Spring Boot application, connected to a PostgreSQL database.
In this application one of the endpoints is supposed to set some fields to NULL on one of my entities.

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@TypeDef(name = "jsonb", typeClass = JsonBinaryType.class)
public class Assessment extends AbstractEntity {
    ...

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "disputer_id")
    private User disputer;

    @Type(type = "jsonb")
    @Column(columnDefinition = "jsonb")
    @Basic(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Form dispute;
    ...
    private String disputeFeedback;
    ...
}
```

**For some reason, in some cases, the dispute field (of type JSONB, using com.vladmihalcea.hibernate.type.json.JsonBinaryType) is not set to NULL.**

I've tried the following combinations of setups:

```
1. 
- application: Spring Boot on my local machine
- database: setup using Docker on my local machine
- result: all 3 fields from above set to NULL
```

```
2. 
- application: on my local machine
- database: PostgreSQL in a Kubernetes container (test environment)
- result: all 3 fields from above set to NULL
```

```
3. 
- application: Spring Boot in a Kubernetes container (test environment)
- database: PostgreSQL in a Kubernetes container (test environment)
- result: all fields except the JSONB field set to NULL.
```

I enabled the SQL logs and I noticed that for some reason, for the third setup, the jsonb column is not included in the update script at all:

```
Hibernate: 
    update
        assessment 
    set
        ...
        dispute_feedback=?,
        disputer_id=?,
        ...
        time_of_last_status_change=?
    where
        id=?
...
2020-02-26 12:48:59.553 TRACE 1 --- [nio-8090-exec-1] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [4] as [VARCHAR] - [null]
2020-02-26 12:48:59.553 TRACE 1 --- [nio-8090-exec-1] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [5] as [OTHER] - [null]
...
2020-02-26 12:48:59.554 TRACE 1 --- [nio-8090-exec-1] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [14] as [TIMESTAMP] - [2020-02-26T12:48:59.500787Z]
```

Do the JSONB columns combined with Hibernate have some kinds of limitations when it comes to updating them? Although I've previously worked with them and didn't encounter such issues.

Thank you

---

**Update 1:**
I tried adding the @DynamicUpdate annotation to my entity and now the column is set to NULL in the test environment as well, but this still leaves me wondering why this column was not included in the first version of the update script.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a bug in Hibernate.

I noticed you have enabled lazy loading on the JSON entity attribute:

```
@Basic(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
```

If you have bytecode enhancement enabled as well, try removing the `@Basic(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)` annotation and see if the problem still replicates.

It might be a bytecode enhancement issue in Hibernate ORM.